# How to run a subfunction which is element of an array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, window

I try to reach a subfuntion that is element of an array.

In the below example we can reach the `name` property like `window['name']`.

But if property is a function it can not be called like this. What I try to do is in `.each` function if item is a function run the function. How can I do that ?.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var human = {
    name: 'Emin',
    surname: 'Çiftçi',
    job: 'Software Developer',
    func: function() {
      alert(name + ' ' + surname + ', ' + job);
    }
  };

  $.each(human, function(index, item) {
    //if(item is a function) {
    // run the function
    //}
    $('<div>').text(index + ': ' + item).appendTo('#deneme');

  });
});
```

Comment: as i can see, your use of jquery each seem to be good, try to make a console log of the var and see the console output and tell us

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

PS: You also need to fix the name, surname and job in the alert

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var human = {
    name: 'Emin',
    surname: 'Çiftçi',
    job: 'Software Developer',
    func: function() {
      alert(human.name + ' ' + human.surname + ', ' + human.job);
    }
  };

  $.each(human, function(name, item) {
    console.log(typeof item);
    if (typeof item == "function") item();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you sir, worked. `typeof` is save the day :)
Edit: Yes, I realize now that I must change them. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `typeof`:

```
 if(typeof item === 'function'){
      item(); // run it
 }
```

Comment: I fixed yours for you  ;)

Comment: But as an object is in the each loop then it would return as keys and values I guess.

Comment: Yes, but the function would still be the second parameter